# Can NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) return multiple entries?

Tags: ios, cocoa

A commonly used method to find the location of the locally writable Library directory on iOS is `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`, like so:

```
    NSString *thedir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
```

which, on ios7, returns `/var/mobile/Applications/<app-GUID>/Library`

My questions:

- On iOS, is `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` above (with the parameters used above) guaranteed to return an array with just one entry all the time?
- If returned array has multiple entries, is it at least guaranteed to be deterministically ordered?
- (This is for my own curiosity) What would cause it to return multiple entries, and what are the other possible entries that it might return?

The (obvious) concern if the returned array is *not* guaranteed to be deterministically ordered: say you write some data to a file within the Library
directory and you want to access it in a subsequent session. How do you know, in the second session, the exact location of the file you wrote in the
first session? (yes, you can write the location onto a file, but then how do you deterministically access the file that stores the location? (short of the
hacky/ugly solution of using NSUserDefaults for everything))

This question also applies to:

- `NSDocumentDirectory` parameter
- `-[NSFileManager URLsForDirectory:inDomains:]`

And yes, from my emprical observation, these methods have always returned a unique entry (when used with `NSUserDomainMask`), but would appreciate authoritative sources (or even references to the
source -- if it is open-sourced)

Answer (score 0):

I can't say anything about guarantees, but from the documentation for [this function](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains) and [the related NSFileManager methods that return URLs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLsForDirectory%3ainDomains%3a) [(which Apple advises you use instead)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLForDirectory%3ainDomain%3aappropriateForURL%3acreate%3aerror%3a), it looks pretty clear that there's supposed to be a one-to-one mapping from values in the `domainMask` parameter to directories in the returned array.

In iOS, you're probably only ever going to see one item in the returned array, because a sandboxed app can only see files in its sandbox — that only contains files for `NSUserDomainMask`, so that's the only domain appropriate to search.

But these APIs are shared with OS X (and reflect a heritage going back to NeXTSTEP), which has a notion of directory domains in the file system. If you were making a Mac app that needs to look for resources that might be installed either at the user level (e.g. in `~/Library`) or at the local-machine level (in `/Library`), or preinstalled with the OS (in `/System/Library`) you'd use one of these APIs to get the appropriate paths, and the order for searching them in (because user resources should override system resources, etc.).